# Writing white-space delimited text to be human readable in Python

Tags: python, whitespace, human-readable

I have a list of lists that looks something like this:

```
data = [['seq1', 'ACTAGACCCTAG'],
        ['sequence287653', 'ACTAGNACTGGG'],
        ['s9', 'ACTAGAAACTAG']]
```

I write the information to a file like this:

```
for i in data:
    for j in i:
        file.write('\t')
        file.write(j)
    file.write('\n')
```

The output looks like this:

```
seq1   ACTAGACCCTAG  
sequence287653   ACTAGNACTGGG  
s9   ACTAGAAACTAG
```

The columns don't line up neatly because of variation in the length of the first element in each internal list. How can I write appropriate amounts of whitespace between the first and second elements to make the second column line up for human readability?

Comment: An interesting related concept: [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a format string:

```
for i,j in data:
    file.write('%-15s %s\n' % (i,j))
```

`%-15s` means left justify a 15-space field for a string.  Here's the output:

```
seq1            ACTAGACCCTAG
sequence287653  ACTAGNACTGGG
s9              ACTAGAAACTAG
```

Comment: Bonus points for simplifying to one loop by unpacking the inner lists directly into `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [['seq1', 'ACTAGACCCTAG'],
        ['sequence287653', 'ACTAGNACTGGG'],
        ['s9', 'ACTAGAAACTAG']]
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join('%-15s %s' % (i,j) for i,j in data) )
```

for me is even clearer than expression with loop

Answer (score 0):

`"%10s" % obj` will ensure minimum 10 spaces with the string representation of obj aligned on the right.

`"%-10s" % obj` does the same, but aligns to the left.